# How i get client side input html value to the server side in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to solve this error but after execution variable stored null values. Please tell me how I get client side html input value to the server side

Below is the HTML Code :

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" name="firstname"/>
```

and below is the Server Code :

```
string firstname=Convert.ToString(Request.Form["firstname"]);
```

Comment: please add some code examples of what you have tried so far.

Comment: am trying this code:-                                                                                 
 string fname = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["firstname"]);

Comment: is your control inside of a form tag marked with the post action?. Check web developer tools network tab and make sure the value is actually getting posted

Comment: yes i defined method="post" in form tag but it is not work properly

Comment: thanks Mr.Alexander now i fix that problem, it work........

Answer (score 0):

your code is so tiny incomplete ...if you want to pass some value from html  to your server side variables...you have multiple options...one of them is is using`request.Form[]`....but for this option you have to pass your input value to a controller by this parameter : `ActionName(FormCollection frm)` so check to see does your action have any FormCollection parameter or not...then you can use `Request.Form["firstname"]`

you can see a complete example here: [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-formcollection-in-mvc-controller/)

pay: your input most to be inside a form! like `Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName")`...

```
       public void savedata(FormCollection fomr)
    {
        string name = Request.Form["name"];
        string surname = Request.Form["surname"];
        string age = Request.Form["age"];
        string gender = Request.Form["gender"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same name in both MVC and HTML sides:

**MVC:**

```
public ActionResult exp(string YourChosenName)
{
    retun view(); 
}
```

**and HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="YourChosenName" />
```